# Objects not following curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, edit-mode, fcurves

I'm having a bit of a trouble with the curve modifier. The object seems to not be following the curve. I have checked other threads and posts about the similar problem, and I followed their given solutions. Still, the issue remains. What do you guys think might be the problem to this. I have provided a screenshot with my blend file.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49106

[image]

Comment: if you move your object on the Z and Y axis so that it sticks to your curve, it will work

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that.